# How to count the number of "days" between 2 date in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Considering a `ee.DateRange` or 2 `ee.Date`, how can I count the number of unit between the 2 dates?

For example:

```py
dates = ee.DateRange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31')
nbDays = my_custom_method(dates, unit="day") 
>>> 31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference function for this:

```
ee.Date('2020-01-31').difference(ee.Date('2020-01-01'), 'days')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proposal, I would be happy to accept someone else answer if it uses more idiomatic structures.

I cannot count or make operations on dates so I guess movig to millis timestamp is the only way forward. What I do is transform start and end into numbers, build a sequence from it using as an interval the length of the unit in millisecond.
Finally I just have to count them:

```js
var dates = ee.DateRange('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31')
var start = dates.start().millis()
var end = dates.end().millis()
var unitMillis = ee.Dictionary({"day": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24})
  
var dateList = ee.List.sequence(start, end, unitMillis.get("day"))

var nbIntervals = dateList.size().subtract(1)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c397777e1e6a295517bb4b01899ea030

PS: one can update this code by adding the other duration to the dictionnary.